# Remove all digits attached to a word - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a string like

```
'Dogs are highly5 variable12 in1 height and weight. 123'
```

and I want to get

```
'Dogs are highly variable in height and weight. 123'
```

How can I do this?

Here's my existing code:

```py
somestr = 'Dogs are highly5 variable12 in1 height and weight. 123'

for i, char in enumerate(somestr):
    if char.isdigit():
        somestr = somestr[:i] + somestr[(i+1):]
```

but it returns

```
'Dogs are highly variable1 n1 hight and weight. 123'
```

Comment: Think about what i and char are as you remove characters from the string.

Comment: Removing items while iterating over a sequence can cause problems - https://sopython.com/canon/95/removing-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-the-list/ . You would be better off constructing a new string out of characters that are `not char.isdigit`. ... [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Do you want to remove digits that are not attached to a word? For example, what result do you want if `somestr = 'I have 8 dogs'`?

Comment: You'll have to explain what "that close to word" means.

Comment: You mean only digits that *are* attached to a word must be removed, right?  E.g. all digits were removed in your output "Dogs are highly variable in height and weight'"

Comment: Yes, only digits that are attached to a word must be removed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Given**

```
import string


s = "Here is a state0ment with2 3digits I want to remove, except this 1."
```

**Code**

```
def remove_alphanums(s):
    """Yield words without attached digits."""
    for word in s.split():
        if word.strip(string.punctuation).isdigit():
            yield word
        else:
            yield "".join(char for char in word if not char.isdigit())
```

**Demo**

```
" ".join(remove_alphanums(s))
# 'Here is a statement with digits I want to remove, except this 1.'
```

---

**Details**

We use a generator to yield either independent digits (with or without punctuation) or filtered words via a [generator expression](https://dev.to/vmesel/what-the-heck-are-python-generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions-55hh).

Comment: It will remove all digits, but I want remove only attached to word digits

Comment: Since you've edited the question, I'll edit this answer shortly.

Comment: Revised.  I suggest adding punctuation to your example, as it changes the solutions you'll get, e.g. `'123'` is a digit while `'123.'` is not.